# Why string is ignored in sql query using express when passing in req.params.id?

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I am using express with mysql querying an events database. Everything is working fine but I want to make sure that all undefine routes are properly redirected. I am accessing and displaying the events by their id. I managed to make the redirection when I enter a totally different event id but if I add a random string behind the event id, the query still works - why is that?

So for example:

/32516 -> works as it's a valid id 
/32516gjklktj -> still works, why? 
/94535 -> doesn't work as it's not a valid id

I am using mysql as the database and the mysql npm package

Events route:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    let eventId = req.params.id

    async.parallel({
      one: function(callback) {
        pool.query(db.EventInfo, [eventId], (err, results) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback(null, results);
        });
      },
      two: function(callback) {
        pool.query(db.Bookings, [eventId], (err, results) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          callback(null, results);
        });
      }
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results.one[0] === undefined) {
          res.redirect('/')
        } else {
        res.render('event', {
            event: results.one[0],
            bookings: results.two,
        });
    }});
  })
```

Database query:

```
let db = {
        EventInfo: 
            `SELECT id, title, date, location FROM events 
                WHERE eventId=?`,
        Bookings:
            `SELECT firstName, lastName FROM bookings
                WHERE eventId=?`
};
```

What am I missing? I am still new to coding but learning hard and fast :)

Comment: Which database are you using? Educated guess: implicit conversion to `INT`, eventId is most likely defined as integer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=992ef2bd65b44a8bcda3daed36e067fb

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Hi, it's a mysql database and the eventId is indeed an INT, but what is converting it to INT? When I make the query in the terminal it just throws an error?